# Powershell add domain user to ntfs permission to a file

Tags: windows, powershell, ntfs

Im trying to write a script where a part of it take ACL from file and adding specific user ntfs permission to modify:

```
$identity = "$domain\$adname" #In this example $domain='muzi.local $adname='puzi'
$rights = 'Modify'
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'
$propagation = 'None'
$type = 'Allow'

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path "$bucketdir\$_" #for this example c:\bla.txt
$Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE) #this is where the error output.

Set-Acl -Path "$bucketdir\$_" -AclObject $Acl #code would not get here
```

Error output:
Exception calling "AddAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "No flags can be set.
Parameter name: inheritanceFlags"
At C:\Step2.ps1:26 char:3

- ```
      $Acl.AddAccessRule($ACE)
  ```
- ```
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException

Looks like the arguments aren't passing to the function, but if I output them one by one it looks fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you simply forgot to create the new access rule, but also, since you're changing the ACL of a File, not a Directory, you should use the constructor for the new rule which has only 3 parameters, since a file does not have child objects to propagate or inherit access rights:

```
$identity    = "$domain\$adname" #In this example $domain='muzi.local $adname='puzi'
$rights      = 'Modify'
$type        = 'Allow'
# these do not apply for a File (it has no child objects)
# $inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'
# $propagation = 'None'

$file = "$bucketdir\$_" #for this example c:\bla.txt

# create the new AccessRule
$rule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new($identity, $rights, $type)

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $file
$Acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl -Path $file -ACLObject $Acl
```

Comment: still error, i decided to leave it and use icacls, thanks for helping